# Rabbitmq on docker: Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm trying to launch Rabbitmq with docker-compose alongside DRF and Celery.
Here's my docker-compose file. Everything else works fine, except for rabbitmq:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  drf:
    build: ./drf
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command:
      - |
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./drf/:/usr/src/drf/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=base_test

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    depends_on:
      - drf

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - net_1

  celery_worker:
    command: sh -c "wait-for redis:3000 && wait-for drf:8000 -- celery -A base-test worker -l info"
    depends_on:
      - drf
      - db
      - redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
    hostname: celery_worker
    image: app-image
    networks:
      - net_1
    restart: on-failure

  celery_beat:
    command: sh -c "wait-for redis:3000 && wait-for drf:8000 -- celery -A mysite beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"
    depends_on:
      - drf
      - db
      - redis
    hostname: celery_beat
    image: app-image
    networks:
      - net_1
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  net_1:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  redis:
```

And here's what happens when I launch it. Can someone please help me find the problem? I can't even follow the instruction and read the generated dump file because rabbitmq container exits after the error.

```
rabbitmq         |   Starting broker...2021-04-05 16:49:58.330 [info] <0.273.0>
rabbitmq         |  node           : rabbit@0e652f57b1b3
rabbitmq         |  home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
rabbitmq         |  config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
rabbitmq         |  cookie hash    : ZPam/SOKy2dEd/3yt0OlaA==
rabbitmq         |  log(s)         : <stdout>
rabbitmq         |  database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@0e652f57b1b3
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.542 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.542 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.542 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [x] empty_basic_get_metric
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.542 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [x] implicit_default_bindings
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.542 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [x] maintenance_mode_status
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.542 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.543 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.545 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:09.546 [info] <0.273.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.844 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step pre_boot defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.845 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.846 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step rabbit_alarm defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.854 [info] <0.414.0> Memory high watermark set to 2509 MiB (2631391641 bytes) of 6273 MiB (6578479104 bytes) total
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.864 [info] <0.416.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.864 [info] <0.416.0> Disk free limit set to 50MB
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.872 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step code_server_cache defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.872 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step file_handle_cache defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.872 [info] <0.419.0> Limiting to approx 1048479 file handles (943629 sockets)
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.873 [info] <0.420.0> FHC read buffering:  OFF
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.873 [info] <0.420.0> FHC write buffering: ON
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.874 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step worker_pool defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.874 [info] <0.372.0> Will use 4 processes for default worker pool
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.874 [info] <0.372.0> Starting worker pool 'worker_pool' with 4 processes in it
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.876 [info] <0.273.0> Running boot step database defined by app rabbit
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.899 [info] <0.273.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.900 [info] <0.273.0> Successfully synced tables from a peer
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.908 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
rabbitmq         |
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.908 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.908 [error] <0.273.0>
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.908 [error] <0.273.0> BOOT FAILED
rabbitmq         | BOOT FAILED
rabbitmq         | ===========
rabbitmq         | Error during startup: {error,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.909 [error] <0.273.0> ===========
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.909 [error] <0.273.0> Error during startup: {error,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.909 [error] <0.273.0>                           {schema_integrity_check_failed,
rabbitmq         |                           {schema_integrity_check_failed,
rabbitmq         |                               [{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.910 [error] <0.273.0>                               [{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.910 [error] <0.273.0>                                    [name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.911 [error] <0.273.0>                                     arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.911 [error] <0.273.0>                                     recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,
rabbitmq         |                                    [name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,
rabbitmq         |                                     arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.911 [error] <0.273.0>                                     gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.911 [error] <0.273.0>                                     slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.912 [error] <0.273.0>                                    [name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.912 [error] <0.273.0>                                     arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.913 [error] <0.273.0>                                     recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.913 [error] <0.273.0>                                     gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.913 [error] <0.273.0>                                     slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,
rabbitmq         |                                     recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,
rabbitmq         |                                     gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,
rabbitmq         |                                     slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],
rabbitmq         |                                    [name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,
rabbitmq         |                                     arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,
rabbitmq         |                                     recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,
rabbitmq         |                                     gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,
rabbitmq         |                                     slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,
rabbitmq         |                                     type,type_state]}]}}
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.914 [error] <0.273.0>                                     type,type_state]}]}}
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:10.916 [error] <0.273.0>
rabbitmq         |
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:11.924 [info] <0.272.0> [{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.272.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info
,{exit,{{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_
pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_
pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,type,type_state]}]},{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,138}]},{proc_l
ib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.271.0>]},{message_queue_len,1},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.273.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.271.0>,<0.44.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{
status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,28},{reductions,534}], []
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:11.924 [error] <0.272.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.272.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,[name
,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],[name
,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_owner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,type,t
ype_state]}]},...} in application_master:init/4 line 138
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:11.924 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_o
wner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_o
wner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,type,type_state]}]},...}
rabbitmq         | 2021-04-05 16:50:11.925 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_o
wner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusive_o
wner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,type,type_state]}]},...}
rabbitmq         | {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusi
ve_owner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options],[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusi
ve_owner,arguments,pid,slave_pids,sync_slave_pids,recoverable_slaves,policy,operator_policy,gm_pids,decorators,state,policy_version,slave_pids_pending_shutdown,vhost,options,type,type_state]}]},{rabbit,start,
[normal,[]]}}}"}
rabbitmq         | Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_attributes_mismatch,rabbit_queue,[name,durable,auto_delete,exclusiv
e_owner,arg
rabbitmq         |
rabbitmq         | Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
rabbitmq exited with code 0
```

Comment: I have started to experience the same but in k8s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by removing `container_name` and `volumes` from rabbitmq section of docker-compose file. Still would be nice to have an explanation of this behavior.

Comment: but removing volumes will cause to loose all the data :0

Comment: @MohammadhosseinFereydouni It didn't cause any loss of data. I don't have enough knowledge to say why but I'd recommend reading this: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/.

Comment: when you remove rabbitmq volume, the container no longer points to the existing data so it won't have the exchanges and other things defined in it before the error.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, the same error (`Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped`) appears when you have syntax errors in your `definitions.json`.